# LXDE preferences lacks Default Applications applet

Tags: lxde, default-programs

I've just installed LXDE under Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm finding it much more agreeable.

One of the few problems is the fact that the network status widget/panel doesn't show up. I've read this is a known problem and that it can be fixed by manually adding the nw-applet to my default applications list.

The problem is that there is no Default Applications tab in my Preferences menu. Have I missed it or how can I add it back in if it really is missing for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu 14.04 already has LXDE setup for Ubuntu with a default application tool in Preferences and a brand new repo you can add for up-to-date fixes and updates that have sorted the network manager problem...

Install Lubuntu or in your current Ubuntu setup install lubuntu-desktop to have same distro, then when finished reboot and in Terminal type:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lubuntu-dev/staging

Comment: Will installing lubuntu-desktop and then adding the development repository ‘magically’ rectify the missing nw-applet problem? 

In future if I want to adjust Default Applications how can I adjust them if my applet for doing so continues to be missing?

Comment: instead of complaining did you actually try installing lubuntu-desktop and adding the repo for the new udpates ?  I did exactly that and on 3 of my computers the network manager is working once more and the default applilcations settings are in the Preferences menu...

Comment: Yes I have done that. I'm enjoying the LXDE experience but I am a little annoyed by some issues which I have not experience while booting directly into Lubuntu. Though I suppose this works so I had better keep it now. Can anybody point me in the direction of resources that explain how to set up the synaptics trackpad and the touchscreen under LXDE? And how do I bind the infamous Windows key to the LXDE main menu? There must be good resources out there!

Comment: CHeck here for mouse and trackpad setup as well as other Lubuntu settings: http://lubuntu.net/blog/lubuntu-screencast-configure-touchpad